# How to attach Glassfish source in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, documentation, attachment

I'm using Glassfish server for developing JavaEE web aplications in Eclipse oxygen.
I would like to attach the source code for Glassfish to explore the APIs documentation.

PS: The Java source part works fine, the web part is what I'm looking for. Since I'm novice, please go easy on me.

[HttpServletRequest.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFR6h.png)

[image: img]

Comment: jdk contains a `src.zip` file, point to it

Comment: Yeah, that solves the problem for Java libraries, but not the JavaEE part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Download** the source JAR of `javax.servlet-api.jar` version 4.0

   - from [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.0) - deep link: [`javax.servlet-api-4.0.0-sources.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.0/javax.servlet-api-4.0.0-sources.jar)
   - or from [maven.java.net](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.0/) - deep link: [`javax.servlet-api-4.0.0-sources.jar`](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.0/javax.servlet-api-4.0.0-sources.jar)
2. In Eclipse click the ***Attache Source...*** button (which is also visible in your screenshot) and specify the location of the downloaded file.